# iOS - Write to (or read from) file failure

Tags: ios, nsdata, writetofile

Here is my code:

```
-(NSArray *)getSpecialArray:(NSString *)day{
    NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@%@", @"http://www.myDomain.com/", day, @".txt"];;
    stringURL = [stringURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSString *filePath;

    if ( urlData )
    {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Area/%@%@", documentsDirectory, day, @".txt"];
        [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }

    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

    if(content == nil){
        content = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }

    content = [content stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Main Menu\n" withString:@""];

    splitData = [content componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\n\n"]];


    return splitData;
}
```

What seems to be happening is that the write to file section is not working. Content seems to always == nil on that line. It also could be that it is writing just fine and it's not reading the file well for whatever reason, though I'm leaning towards the former option. Anyone see any problems with this code? Assume this is the first time running this code and the folder and file being written to doesn't exist. This problem seemed to occur right after switching to Mountain Lion and upgrading Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in creating the URL.

```
NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@%@", @"http://www.myDomain.com/", day, @".txt"];
```

You are appending `"/"` in formatter as well as with URL value.
So your final URL will become `http://www.myDomain.com//filename.txt`. This is a invalid URL.

Correct it by removing `"/"` from either of place.

```
NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", @"http://www.myDomain.com/", day, @".txt"];
```

Comment: I was convinced this would fix it, but I was wrong. Content is still nil.

Answer (score 0):

At first, check if your file is actually created on filesystem and/or check returning value of `[urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];` call.

If file exists and method returns `YES`, then the problem is in the reading data. Pass `NSError**` to `stringWithContentsOfFile: encoding: error:` and check it. Also, don't use `NULL` for objects, instead use `nil`.

Comment: How exactly do I check the return value of that? I've never done that before. This is my first iPhone app, so really I'm not too certain how to do either of those.

Comment: BOOL result = [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; if (!result){NSLog(@"ERROR occured");}

Comment: I'm getting result=NO.

Comment: It means that writing was unsuccessful. Use writeToFile:options:error to get specific error.

Comment: I figured it out, I can no longer write NSData to it, I have to first convert it to a string. Instead of me writing the code down, why don't you edit your answer to include the following so I can give you credit:         path = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory].path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", day, @".txt"]];
        [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]  writeToFile:path atomically:YES
                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

Comment: Actually, the problem came back. What I found was that if I write it to Documents, it works just fine. If I write it to a new sub-directory of Documents, it doesn't work. Maybe I need to create the folder first for it to work?